# repeater conditional view with no data logic

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webcontrol

on my repeater i builed a table and want to show a colum just for user that is in role admin.
i need to remove the column in the HeaderTemplate and in ItemTemplate.
i could use data logic and add a db column that will be boolean, but then i need to send to the SP the user role.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="TemplatesList" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    #
                </th>
                <th>
                    Title
                </th>
                <th>
                    Subject
                </th>
                <th>
                    &nbsp;
                </th>
                <th>
                    &nbsp;
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("ET_ID")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("ET_Title")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("ET_Subject")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="<%# VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Admin/EmailsTemplates/Delete.aspx?id="+Eval("ET_ID").ToString())%>">
                    Delete</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="<%# VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Admin/EmailsTemplates/Edit.aspx?id="+Eval("ET_ID").ToString())%>">
                    Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide the column than you can use LoginView control which can select content based on roles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx

it should work within templates

or you can use inline scripting, something like this:

```
<% if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) { %>
<td> xxx </td>
<% } %>
```